# How to create a custom HTML li dot with correct indent

Tags: html, css

I want to create a kind of inventory where each `li` represents an item and the dot should be replaced with the amount of the items in the inventory, e.g.:

```
10x  Item1
1x   Item2
100x Item3
```

I tried this but it doesn't seem quite right, especially the indent (especially when the width of the wrapper is limited):

```css
ul{
  list-style: none;
  margin-left: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
}
    
li {
  padding-left: 1em;
  text-indent: -1em;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

li:before{
  content: 'x' attr(data-item-count) ' ';
}
```

```html
<div style="width:100px;border:1px solid #000">
  <ul>
      <li data-item-count="1">Health potion</li>
      <li data-item-count="10">Fire scroll</li>
      <li data-item-count="104">Skull</li>
  </ul>
<div>
```

Comment: Seems like over engineering a problem that borders on the http://xyproblem.info/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use position absolute on the `before` and use padding-left on `li` equal to `before` max-width. So, supposing you will have max `x1234` you should consider that in the padding size.

See below

```css
ul{
  list-style: none;
  margin-left: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
}
    
li {
 

  padding-right: 10px;
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 40px;

  position:relative;
}

li:before{
  content: 'x' attr(data-item-count) ' ';
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
}
```

```html
<div style="width:100px;border:1px solid #000">
  <ul>
      <li data-item-count="1">Health potion</li>
      <li data-item-count="10">Fire scroll</li>
      <li data-item-count="104">Skull</li>
  </ul>
<div>
```

Comment: Thanks, for my use case this works. It's not that obvious that the padding is fixed.

Comment: @DoubleVoid glad i could help. Cheers ! :D

Answer (score 2):

If you need to keep this unordered list markup you could do some positioning with `inline-block`.

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin-left: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}

li:before {
  content: 'x' attr(data-item-count) ' ';
  padding-right: 1rem;
  width: 2rem;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li data-item-count="1">Health potion</li>
  <li data-item-count="10">Fire scroll</li>
  <li data-item-count="104">Skull</li>
</ul>
```

---

However, this seems like a good candidate for a [`<dl>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dl) and `display: grid`

> Common uses for this element are to implement a glossary or to display metadata *(a list of key-value pairs)*.

```css
dl {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
  grid-column-gap: 0.3em;
  grid-row-gap: 0.5em;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 5px;
}

dt,
dd {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<dl>
  <dt>x1</dt>
  <dd>Health potion</dd>
  <dt>x10</dt>
  <dd>Fire scroll</dd>
  <dt>x104</dt>
  <dd>Skull</dd>
  <dt>x105</dt>
  <dd>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</dd>
</dl>
```

Comment: Hi thanks :) I forgot that my inventory has limited width on mobile devices. I updated my question. items that use muliple lines are having no correct indent.

Comment: Edited with an alternate soution

Comment: Thanks. I like the solution. But this way I have to keep track of two element (I know I could wrap them) :D Voted up anyway!